# Object.entries loop only returns first entry

Tags: javascript

I have an object that looks like this:

```
myObject = {a: 'hello', b: 2323, c: 123}
```

I'm trying to loop through and return key and value for each entry with the following function:

```
returnSomeData(myObject) {
 for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(myObject)) {
    return (
      `${key}: ${value}`
    );
  }
}
```

Currently, only the first entry (a: hello) gets returned. Does anyone know why I'm not getting all entries in the object?

Comment: Because you are returning a result inside the for loop, of course it will return. Return means return (to the parent stack), it means a function yields a result and does not execute the code after it has returned.

Comment: When you think looping something and started to write `for`, slowly stop writing, take a breath, delete `for` and look the documentation for `map`, `filter` and even `reduce` :)

Comment: Appreciate the feedback :) Was following this example before:
https://www.bram.us/2016/11/24/es6es2015-looping-over-an-object-with-keys-and-values/

Comment: You are welcome :) I tried to explain the difference in the accepted answer's comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are returning from the first iteration in the `for` loop. The `return` statement renders the `for` loop utterly useless. You should group the results in an array and then return them after the `for` loop finishes:

```
returnSomeData(myObject) {
  const results = [];
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(myObject)) {
    results.push(
      `${key}: ${value}`
    );
  }
  return results;
}
```

You can also use `map` like so:

```
returnSomeData(myObject) {
  return Object.entries(myObject).map(([key, value]) => `${key}: ${value}`);
}
```

**Example:**

```js
function returnSomeData(myObject) {
  return Object.entries(myObject).map(([key, value]) => `${key}: ${value}`);
}

let myObject = {a: 'hello', b: 2323, c: 123};
let result = returnSomeData(myObject);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: For the second option,  put a return there or use an arrow function, drop curlies and use without a return.

Comment: Great, thanks a lot! I was following this example before:
https://www.bram.us/2016/11/24/es6es2015-looping-over-an-object-with-keys-and-values/

Comment: @Patrick1904, your case is a little bit different. The tutorial you gave here is an example of doing something in a `for` loop. This example there is `console.log`. You can do things in a for loop but you can't return all the items like that. You need to push them somewhere else or better use a `map` like here.

Comment: @devserkan, yes, thank you for explaining that it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

use console.log instead of return. When you return the function stops running or maybe you want to use another function.